# Firefox, developer tools and file download in separate (temporary) tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I have a website that do xhr that will result in file download. FF open new tabl for that filedownload, and XHR request will not be shown on network tab on original page.

How can I get request info for that xhr (best if I could get file download as response, so that I get both request and response info)?

Comment: `FF open new tabl for that filedownload` - avoid this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I found that would force FF to keep file download connection in current tab:

`about:config`

`browser.link.open_newwindow` when set to `1` will do just that.

With it, download http request shows up normally in developers tools.